# Mapping subclasses in ternary relationships

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Is it alright for an attribute in a composite primary key in an intermediate table to be null? I have a ternary relationship and two of the entities have subclasses. The subclasses have their own unique primary keys. The intermediate table’s primary key consists of the subclass primary keys (see image below), so there are times when some of the attributes would be null.

I made orders into an intermediate table. You can see there will be times when these attributes would be null. For instance a customer orders something from the restaurant menu then catering order id would be null. Is it alright to it do this way? If not how should it be done?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composite key fields can't be null. `customer` and `menu` should be hiding their respective abstractions so that `order`s don't have a hard dependency on a particular type of customer or menu. If you need an intermediate table, give it a synthetic primary key and have it handle the distinction between restaurant and catering menus. Use table inheritance (if you've got Postgres) or views to represent the full data sets for each type of customer or menu.

But first make sure you really need to split those tables up -- it's okay for foreign keys to be null, but fewer tables and foreign keys in the first place make the application logic easier.

Comment: So for the intermediate orders() table, should I swap the two primary keys coming from the menu subclass tables restaurant and catering menu? So replace those two keys with the primary key from the superclass menu and then use three foreign keys to link that primary key back to those three tables?

Comment: `orders` should have `customer_id` and `menu_id` foreign keys, each a single column referring to a single-column primary key in `customers` and `menus` respectively. If you need to break out restaurant and catering menus into separate tables (think very carefully about this -- sparse data in one table isn't the worst thing in the world!), `menus` should have `restaurant_menu_id` and `catering_menu_id` foreign keys, either of which may be null. You can use check constraints to ensure that at least one has a value.